# Verify approach - Use recursion to write Java method for determining if a String s has more vowels than consonants

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to solve above problem. Below is my solution. Appreciate feedback/comments.

```
public static boolean areMoreVowels(String str, int c, int v){
    String vowels = "aeiou";

    if(vowels.indexOf(str.charAt(0))>=0){
        v++;
    }else{
        c++;
    }

    if(str.length()==1){
        return v > c;   
    }

    return areMoreVowels(str.substring(1), c, v);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(areMoreVowels("aeiouttrrrrr", 0, 0));
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question? Is this not working? This isn't really a "code review" site.

Comment: I don't like the way I call the function first time. My question is, is there a better way to solve this ?

Comment: I don't understand why you would use recursion to do this. A simple for loop should be easy enough.

Comment: @smead - because the problem says so..

Comment: Well then it's a stupid problem. There are way better problems to learn about recursion with. I wouldn't waste your time trying to perfect it, if what you wrote works :)

Comment: @intvprep Please read: [What should I do when someone answers my question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

I think your code it's ok! But if you look for other way, another idea could be

```
Int areMoreVowels(string str, int pos)
    if  pos == str.length()
        return 0
    k = areMoreVowels(str, pos+1)
    if str[pos] == Vowel()
        return k + 1
    return k - 1

main()
    if areMoreVowels("aeiouttrrrrr", 0) > 0 
        print "Yes"
    else
        print "No"
```

Comment: appreciate your response. Will check out your approach as well. Is that in Python ?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd split this up into two separate problems for simplicity:

- counting vowels
- verifying whether the number of vowels is greater than that of vowels

Something along these lines:

```
count_vowels(str, p):
    if p == len(str) return 0

    return count_vowels(str, p + 1) + (is_vowel(str[p]) ? 1 : 0)

more_vowels(str):
    return count_vowels(str, 0) > (len(str) / 2)
```

Assigning a single, simple purpose to each method is generally a better approach than creating a conditional structure to squeeze separate functionality into a single method.

Comment: Good suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine. I don't know if you are aware of it or not, but you used [tail recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion) which really matters in some languages (like Scala), and can reduce chance for stack overflow. Also your method already return your answer, what I would consider as an advantage.
You can consider reducing amount of variables:

```
public static boolean areMoreVowels(String str, int v){
  String vowels = "aeiou"; //do you consider 'y' as a vovel?

  if (vowels.indexOf(str.charAt(0)) >= 0) {
    v++;
  } else {
    v--;
  }

  if (str.length() == 1) {
    return v > 0;
  }

  return areMoreVowels(str.substring(1), v);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(areMoreVowels("aeiouttrrrrr", 0, 0));
}
```